# How to give color to placeholders

Tags: html, css

I am making a form in which i am using placeholder like

```
<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='please write your name here'>
```

How can I give color to this placeholder.

like color of 'please write your name here' is green.

Comment: have you tried goolging it first? like `css how to change input placeholder` ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/2610497/4323504

Comment: do some research first before you ask a question, this already have many answers out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

Source : [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/)